# Iterating through functions and outputting results in organized pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hoping to output a clean dataframe that shows the model name, the parameters used in the model, and the resulting scoring metrics. Would be even better if there was a smarter way to iterate through the metric functions (given the varying parameters). [Example picture of what I'm aiming for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx9s0.png)

Here's what I have so far:

```
def train_predict_score(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
    y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)

    result = []
    result.append(roc_auc_score(y_train, y_pred_train))
    result.append(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_test))
    result.append(cohen_kappa_score(y_train, y_pred_train))
    result.append(cohen_kappa_score(y_test, y_pred_test))
    result.append(f1_score(y_train, y_pred_train, pos_label=1))
    result.append(f1_score(y_test, y_pred_test, pos_label=1))
    result.append(precision_score(y_train, y_pred_train, pos_label=1))
    result.append(precision_score(y_test, y_pred_test, pos_label=1))
    result.append(recall_score(y_train, y_pred_train, pos_label=1))
    result.append(recall_score(y_test, y_pred_test, pos_label=1))

    return result

# Initialize default models
clf1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
clf3 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
clf4 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)

results = []

# Build initial models
for clf in [clf1, clf2, clf3, clf4]:
    result = []
    result.append(clf) # name and parameters - how can I show all info? it gets truncated
    result.append(train_predict_score(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)) # how to parse this out into individual columns?
    results.append(result)

results = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['clf', 'auc_train', 'auc_test', 'f1_train', 'f1_test', 'prec_train',
                                         'prec_test', 'recall_train', 'recall_test'])
results
```

Comment: Please edit your post with an example of what you want your data frame to look like.

Comment: Just added a link to an example output.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'it doesn't work?'

Comment: That was in reference to an old version that I had edited. It now runs, but isn't right. I'll change the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Iterating through functions

Because functions are objects, you can make a list out of them and simply iterate over that. So for example:

```
def add1(x):
    return x+1
def sub1(x):
    return x-1
for func in [add1, sub1]:
    print(func(10))
```

yields

```
11
9
```

### Getting model name and parameters

As far as I understand, you want to store the name of a model (e.g. LogisticRegression) and it's parameters in different columns.
First of, you can get the parameters like this:

```
clf.get_params()
```

This returns all model parameters as a dictionary.
For getting the model name, you can take the string representation of the model and split it once on '('. The first element of the resulting list is the name of the model. So

```
>>>clf
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

becomes

```
>>>str(clf).split('(',1)[0]
LogisticRegression
```

### Example

Here is a small example that should do what you want. It trains 3 different classifiers on sklearn's breast_cancer dataset and returns the `roc_auc`, `f1`, `precision` and `recall` score on both the train- and test-set as a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

#load and split example dataset
X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

#classifiers with default parameters
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier()
clf3 = SVC()
clf_list = [clf1, clf2, clf3]

results_list = []

for clf in clf_list:
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    res = {}
    #extract the model name from the object string
    res['Model'] = str(clf).split('(', 1)[0]
    #get parameters via get_params() method
    res['Parameters'] = clf.get_params()

    #for every metric, record performance on train and test set
    for metric_score in [roc_auc_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score]:
        metric_name = metric_score.__name__
        res[metric_name + '_train'] = metric_score(y_train, clf.predict(X_train))
        res[metric_name + '_test'] = metric_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))

    results_list.append(res)

results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_list)
```

The resulting DataFrame:

```
print(results_df.to_string())

                    Model                                         Parameters   f1_test  f1_train  precision_test  precision_train  recall_test  recall_train  roc_au_test  roc_au_train
0      LogisticRegression  {'fit_intercept': True, 'warm_start': False, '...  0.922384  0.969697        0.922384         0.966038     0.922384      0.973384     0.922384      0.959085
1  RandomForestClassifier  {'criterion': 'gini', 'warm_start': False, 'n_...  0.928137  0.998095        0.928137         1.000000     0.928137      0.996198     0.928137      0.998099
2                     SVC  {'decision_function_shape': None, 'verbose': F...  0.500000  1.000000        0.500000         1.000000     0.500000      1.000000     0.500000      1.000000
```

Note: Because you mentioned DataFrame contents being truncated in your question: That happens only for displaying purposes when you try to print the DF in a console for example, like I did above. When you access the respective cells directly, the content is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome, comprehensive example!